# Can't find the custom font in English language for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, xcode6

I download a third party icon font file, and I drag it into my project and check the target. Everything is OK except when I change the Application Language using English. It show me the origin character but the icon.

Then I println all of the font families, that I can't find the icon font in English, instead in Chinese.

I don't know what happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in application info plist file this :

[image]

Comment: I did that and it works in Chinese not English. Also it displayed ok in Xcode.